# Techniques for Filtering Spiders/Bots during Log Files Analysis

Tags: log-files, website, analytics

I'll begin by telling you what we do.

The measures we have implemented catch a lot of spiders, but we have no idea how many we are missing.  Currently, we apply a set of measures that are obviously partially overlapping:

1. **monitor requests for our robots.txt file**: then of course filter all other requests from same IP address + user agent
2. **compare user agent and IP addresses against published lists**: iab.net and user-agents.org publish the two lists that seem to be the most widely used for this purpose
3. **pattern analysis**: we certainly don't have pre-set thresholds for these metrics but still find them useful.  We look at (i) page views as a function of time (i.e., clicking a lot of links with 200 msec on each page is probative); (ii) the path by which the 'user' traverses out Site, is it systematic and complete or nearly so (like following a back-tracking algorithm); and (iii) precisely-timed visits (e.g., 3 am each day).

Again, I am fairly sure we're getting the low-hanging fruit, but I'm interested in getting the views from the community.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

These Newsletter posts tagged as [Web Log Analysis](http://blog.nihuo.com/tag/web-log-analysis/) at
the commercial [Web log Analyzer from Nihuo](http://www.loganalyzer.net/) site pages could be useful reading.